# Converting from SQL datetime to PHP DateTime, using

Tags: php, sql, datetime, casting

The variable `time_of_last_update` in the database is of type `datetime`, and all I want to do is really print it out in the table (below) but ideally I would like to know for future reference how to cast it/convert it to a DateTime type in PHP, to then use the methods on it such as `->format` etc. Doing:

```
$time_date = $row['time_of_last_update'];
$time_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Seems obvious to me coming from C#, but I get "Call to a member function format() on a non-object", and casting doesn't seem to hep me either. This seems really simple/common, but I cannot find any examples.

```
$describeQuery = 'SELECT username, firstname, surname, location, time_of_last_update      FROM location';
$query = sqlsrv_query($link, $describeQuery);

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>Username</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Surname</th><th>Location</th><th>Time of last Update</th></tr>';

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
// WANT TO CONVERT time_of_last_update (SQL datetime) to a PHP DateTime variable??

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['surname'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['location'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['time_of_last_update'] . '</td>';// RETURNING ERROR "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"
}

echo '</table>';
sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
sqlsrv_close($link);
```

Thanks

Comment: What does `var_dump($row['time_of_last_update']);` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you just want  to display date in correct format, then format it in sql by using DATE_FORMAT:

```
$describeQuery = 'SELECT username, firstname, surname, location, DATE_FORMAT(time_of_last_update, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')      FROM location';
```

2) If you want it as date object in php you need to create it first, before calling method format:

```
// creating new date object
$date_time = new DateTime($row['time_of_last_update']);

//now you can use format on that object:
$formated_date = $date_time->format('d/m/y H:i');
```

Answer (score 1):

See [date and time related extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

```
$dt = date_create($row['time_of_last_update']);

echo date_format($dt, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You should also take a look at [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) if you need a simple API extension for DateTime.